# Tetration Binomial Theorem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, tetration

I was exploring tetration and came across the following identities:

$${^0}(ab) = 1$$
$${^2}(ab) = ({^2}a)^b * ({^2}b)^a$$
$${^3}(ab) = (ab)^({^2}(ab)) = (ab)^{(({^2}a)^b * ({^2}b)^a)}$$

That third identity I would like to close up into a nicer form:

But I don't know how:

what I mean by nicer form is that I want to have:

${^3}a$ and ${^3}b$ in the expression so I can find some sort of binomial theorem generalization for tetration. (Here we work with products as opposed to sums)

Comment: I don't understand what you wrote or your notation

Comment: ^^ is the operation tetration

Comment: Can you define these operations and format your text properly please

Comment: Addition and multiplication are commutative while exponentiation is not. Therefore in complicated exponential formulas there are not as many ways to to rearrange terms to create a simpler formula. Tetration has few results yet, so I suspect that what you would like to achieve can't be done, but that the mathematics to proves it can't be done doesn't exist yet.

Comment: I was actually doing this today, I think I came up with a better solution. I can't give you a generalization though.

Comment: Feel free to share. Hopefully from one user to the next we can inspire a wave of developments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have: $${}^3(ab)$$ you already know that it is equal to: $$(ab)^{({}^2a)^b*({}^2b)^a}$$ from your second equation. So using the fact $$(xy)^z=x^z*y^z$$ you can determine $$a^{({}^2a)^b*({}^2b)^a}*b^{({}^2b)^a*({}^2a)^b}$$ expanding into exponentiation you get $$a^{(a^a)^b*(b^b)^a}*b^{(b^b)^a*(a^a)^b}$$ That and the power of power rule get you $$a^{a^{a*b}*b^{b*a}}*b^{b^{b*a}*a^{a*b}}$$ That is as far as I have gotten; I've tried to put it back into tetration, but I can't because of the $*b$ or $*a$ at the very top.

<sub>***Note:*** I can't shake the feeling I made this worse and not simpler.</sub>